# Symfony 2: ManyToMany Relation and Unique Objects

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm learning SF2 - really impressed with the job done, faced my first real issue I can't solve myself.

I have two entities: Post and Tag. Shortened code below:

```
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="tags", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $posts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param \My\AppBundle\Entity\Snippet $posts
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function addSnippet(\My\AppBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
    {
        $this->posts[] = $posts;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param \My\AppBundle\Entity\Snippet $snippets
     */
    public function removeSnippet(\My\AppBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
    {
        $this->posts->removeElement($posts);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getSnippets()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="posts_tags",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, onDelete="cascade")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, onDelete="cascade")}
     * )
     */
    private $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param \My\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tags
     * @return Snippet
     */
    public function addTag(\My\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags[] = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param \My\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tags
     */
    public function removeTag(\My\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tags);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have M:M relation between two entities.

I have also a form to add Post with embedded Tag collection:

```
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('tags', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new \My\AppBundle\Form\TagType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => true
            ))
        ;
```

TagType form class:

```
$builder->add('name');
```

Everything works as expected. Except one thing: if there's a Tag object with the following name, I'm getting `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation` MySQL error which is obvious. If I apply unique validation constraint I can add a tag to post (if it already exists in database).

It's obvious I need to check if following tag does exist in database and add it only if does not, but... how to do it Symfony way?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: To answer potential questions: no, don't want to use any existing bundle, need to learn it myself with a little help from SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) to handle this. I can't see your annotations on your tags class, or your declaration of 'name' but if you add something like the below it should give you a unique validation constraint based on name with an optional message to throw back.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name", message="This tag name already exists")
 */
class Tag...

/**
 * @var string $name
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
protected $name;
```